# How to disperse personal data before returning?

Tags: algorithm-design, oblivious-transfer, hash-tree

I am working on a project that is dealing with personal data.
The task is to find a method such that when user makes a query into multiple institutions, the result will contain already scattered/dispersed data.

I'll try to give an example:

> The user asks data from institution A and institution B. User sends
> the query: "Find all persons whose age is between 20 and 30 AND has net income over 3000£ a week".
>
> Then institutions sends back data in aggregated form, like "there are 443 persons whose age is between 20 and 30 and net income is <= 3000£."
>
> Or institutions send back dispersed / scattered data without personal information where personal information is hidden.

The main idea is to prevent sending original data out from institutions.

So I am wondering is there any algorithm or any other method that can be used to hide or make this kind of scenario possible?
I have come across with secure multiparty computation and some fragment algorithms, but would like to hear more options.

Comment: This sounds like differential privacy. What is the role of institution B in the above scenario? That is, why can't institution A just return that data?

Comment: Tell me more about differential privacy. Institution A and B are equal, so A can return data but it should be dispersed.

Comment: What do you mean "dispersed"? I don't know very much about differential privacy except that it seems similar to what you want; you will probably learn more from the wikipedia article than from me.